# SQL query to find counts of numbers in running total

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Suppose the table has 1 column ID and the values are as below:

```
ID
5
5
5
6
5
5
6
6
```

the output should be

```
ID  count
5    3
6    1
5    2
6    2
```

How can we do that in a single SQL query.

Comment: If the above one column table is all you have then you _can't_ generate such a running total.  You'd at least need a second column which defines the ordering you want.

Comment: It appears as though you are interested in knowing whether the data are clustered. As Tim indicates above, without some other attribute, it looks like you want to know how the data are physically stored. You can do it with dbms_rowid but I fail to see how such a thing would be useful to anyone other than someone who's trying to optimize a SQL statement by reducing OS read calls.

Comment: Tim is right. This is impossible without an additional column that defines a sort order. Rows in a relational database are **NOT** sorted in any way. Also: you should only add tags for the databases you actually use. Do you really need a solution that works for Oracle **and** Postgres?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql? The solution will probably be depending on the product used.

Comment: I wanted solution for both Oracle and Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relational databases data in the table has no any order, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)

> the database system does not guarantee any ordering of the rows unless
>   an ORDER BY clause is specified in the SELECT statement that queries
>   the table.

therefore, in order to get desired results, you must have an additional colum in the table that defines an order of rows (and can by used in `ORDER BY` clause).

---

In the below examle `cn` column defines such an order:

```
select * from tab123 ORDER BY rn;

        RN ID 
---------- -------
         1 5 
         2 5
         3 5 
         4 6 
         5 5 
         6 5
         7 6
         8 6
```

---

Starting from Oracle version 12c new `MATCH_REGOGNIZE` clause can be used:

```
select * from tab123 
match_recognize(
   order by rn
   measures
     strt.id as id,
     count(*) as cnt
   one row per match
   after match skip past last row
   pattern( strt ss* )
   define ss as ss.id = prev( ss.id )
);
```

---

On earlier versions that support windows function (Oracle 10 and above) you can use two windows functions: `LAG ... over` and `SUM ... over`, in this way

```
select max( id ) as id, count(*) as cnt
FROM (
    select id, sum( xxx ) over (order by rn ) as yyy
    from (
        select t.*,
               case lag( id ) over (order by rn )
               when id then 0 else 1 end as xxx
        from tab123 t
    )
)
GROUP BY yyy
ORDER BY yyy;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the Total count of the Records you have you can write like

**select count(*) from database_name order by column_name;**

Comment: This is **not** what the OP wants. Their required output is a count of `id` which occur in *clusters* - hence the other responses talking about other columns and sort order.